# SQL to LINQ conversion C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to convert this sql statement to linq and need some assistance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM userlocation ul 
       INNER JOIN wins_user w 
               ON ul.locationname = w.location 
WHERE ul.locationname = 'Value' 
        OR ( NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                        FROM mulitcustomeraccess 
                        WHERE userid = 'Value') )
```

Here is my Linq code (usr is `WINS_USER` table):

```
billcodelist = String.Join(
    ",", 
    dc.USERLOCATIONs
        .Where(f => f.LOCATIONNAME == usr.LOCATION || 
               dc.MULITCUSTOMERACCESSes
                   .Where(d => d.USERID == usr.Name)
                   .Select(d => d.LOCATIONNAME)
                   .Contains(f.LOCATIONNAME))
        .Select(f => f.BILLCODECUSTNUMLIST)
        .ToArray());
```

I tried updating my linq code to this

```
billcodelist = String.Join(
    ",", 
    dc.USERLOCATIONs
        .Where(f => f.LOCATIONNAME == usr.LOCATION || 
               !dc.MULITCUSTOMERACCESSes
                   .Any(d => d.USERID == usr.Name)
                   .Select(d => d.LOCATIONNAME)
                   .Contains(f.LOCATIONNAME))
        .Select(f => f.BILLCODECUSTNUMLIST)
        .ToArray());
```

But then I get the following error :

> 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible
>   extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'bool'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) error.

My question is how do I convert that SQL to linq, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: FYI you don't need the `ToArray` as there is an overload of `String.Join` that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: `.Any` returns a bool (`true` if any items meet the condition), but then you try to call `.Select` on the result, which is why you get that error. If the `.Any` is supposed to be part of the `.Where` clause, then you need another closing parenthesis after the `.Any`. You also don't show where `usr` is declared. Don't you want a join in your linq as you do in the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative

```
 var result = from ul in UserLocation
           join winUser in Wins_User on ul.locationName equals winUser.Location
           where ul.locationName == 'value' 
              || !MultiCustomerAccess.Any(x=> x.userId == "value")
           select new { // your projections.}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = USERLOCATION.Join(db.WINS_USER, w => w.LOCATION, ul => ul.locationname, (w, ul) => new {w, ul})
        .Where(_ => _.ul.LOCATIONNAME == 'Value' || !db.MULITCUSTOMERACCESS.Any(m => m.USERID == 'Value'))
        .Select(_ => _.ul.BILLCODECUSTNUMLIST);

var billCodeList = string.Join(",", results);
```

---

Where clauses always expect boolean expressions, you are passing a where into a where but a where does not return a boolean but rather an IQueryable. In the above I used `Any` to evaluate if `MULITCUSTOMERACCESS` has a record where you had used `Where`.